# Right mouse button - activate paste option in input files

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm using angular and I developed a file input. In this input I can detect the image paste using CTRL-V. Is there a way to activate the paste option when I click the right button on the input?

Can someone help me?

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pt6ysm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**code**

```
@HostListener("paste", ["$event"])

  onPaste(e: ClipboardEvent) {
    let clipboardData = e.clipboardData || (window as any).clipboardData;
    let pastedData = clipboardData.getData("text");
    if (pastedData.includes("data:image")) {
      var binary = atob(pastedData.split(",")[1]);
      var array = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
      }
      var pasteImages = new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {
        type: "image/jpeg"
      });
    } else {
      alert("Select an image in the correct format");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to add this just under your paste `HostListener` :

```
@HostListener("mousedown", ["$event"])
onMouseDown(e) {
  if (e.button === 2) {
    e.target.contentEditable = true;
  }
  // wait just enough for 'contextmenu' to fire
  setTimeout(() => (e.target.contentEditable = false), 20);
}
```

And removing the `type=file` from the `input` will allow the context menu to show :

```
<input type="file" id="files" multiple (change)="detectFiles($event)" accept="image/*">
```

Comment: In fact if you remove type = "files" the paste button will appear, however the input will stop working correctly. Is there a way to get them both up and running? Thank you very much for the reply

Comment: @mvpSets My bad, I made you a stackblitz with a custom context menu implementation this morning but forgot to save it... I'll try to make it again tonight if it is interesting for you ? :)

Comment: Yes, I would appreciate it !!! At this moment I want a file input that allows me to select / drag / paste images. You do not need to show the images, just have the events running which would be a huge help! Thank you very much for your availability and willingness to help me!

Comment: I've been looking to see if I can solve this problem, what do I want to achieve is possible or will I have to use several procedures?

Comment: Hey @mvpSets sorry for the delay, I've been looking into your issue and it seems that the main problem is not the context menu really but the access to the clipboard data from Angular. Looks really complex/impossible on some of the browsers. Couldn't allocate that much time in it but my research was not really fructuous.